# How do I use the "enumerate mini template" of the beamer class?

Tags: beamer, templates, enumerate, enumitem

I'm working on a document and tried to change the way enumeration items look with the line

```
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate mini template}{i)}
```

found in the documentation [BeamerUserGuide](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) on page 114.
Whatever I tried, I did not work.
Okay - for now I got a workaround - but I'm interested, how to use that template.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post a full minimal example, and as you have a 'work around' that too would be nice

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Note that you don't have to (and shouldn't) sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: @Hendrik: This is a good hint. Thank you!
I further just found the thread for notifications: I only got a notification (email) for the new answer - but not for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate mini template}{1-\insertenumlabel}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{foo}{bar}
 \begin{enumerate}[<+->][(i)]
  \item foo 
  \item bar
  \item foo
  \item bar
  \item foo
  \item bar  
 \end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good morning Herbert, this is really fine.
I did not know, that it is needed to specify the enumerate item type at the end of the \begin{enumerate} line like here [(i)].
I thought one only needs to use the template. Have I missed that in the documentation? I think it is not explained there, or?
THANK YOU!